# In ROSJava，how can i transform the 'odom' frame to 'map' frame?

Tags: rosjava, android, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
        I want to transform the 'odom' frame to the 'map' frame,but i do not know what i will do? In RosJava i saw a class "Transform".
```

```
package org.ros.rosjava_geometry;

import geometry_msgs.Pose;
import geometry_msgs.PoseStamped;
import org.ros.message.Time;
import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
import org.ros.rosjava_geometry.Quaternion;
import org.ros.rosjava_geometry.Vector3;

public class Transform {
    private Vector3 translation;
    private Quaternion rotationAndScale;

    public static Transform fromTransformMessage(geometry_msgs.Transform message) {
        return new Transform(Vector3.fromVector3Message(message.getTranslation()), Quaternion.fromQuaternionMessage(message.getRotation()));
    }

    public static Transform fromPoseMessage(Pose message) {
        return new Transform(Vector3.fromPointMessage(message.getPosition()), Quaternion.fromQuaternionMessage(message.getOrientation()));
    }

    public static Transform identity() {
        return new Transform(Vector3.zero(), Quaternion.identity());
    }

    public static Transform xRotation(double angle) {
        return new Transform(Vector3.zero(), Quaternion.fromAxisAngle(Vector3.xAxis(), angle));
    }

    public static Transform yRotation(double angle) {
        return new Transform(Vector3.zero(), Quaternion.fromAxisAngle(Vector3.yAxis(), angle));
    }

    public static Transform zRotation(double angle) {
        return new Transform(Vector3.zero(), Quaternion.fromAxisAngle(Vector3.zAxis(), angle));
    }

    public static Transform translation(double x, double y, double z) {
        return new Transform(new Vector3(x, y, z), Quaternion.identity());
    }

    public static Transform translation(Vector3 vector) {
        return new Transform(vector, Quaternion.identity());
    }

    public Transform(Vector3 translation, Quaternion rotation) {
        this.translation = translation;
        this.rotationAndScale = rotation;
    }

    public Transform multiply(Transform other) {
        return new Transform(this.apply(other.translation), this.apply(other.rotationAndScale));
    }

    public Transform invert() {
        Quaternion inverseRotationAndScale = this.rotationAndScale.invert();
        return new Transform(inverseRotationAndScale.rotateAndScaleVector(this.translation.invert()), inverseRotationAndScale);
    }

    public Vector3 apply(Vector3 vector) {
        return this.rotationAndScale.rotateAndScaleVector(vector).add(this.translation);
    }

    public Quaternion apply(Quaternion quaternion) {
        return this.rotationAndScale.multiply(quaternion);
    }

    public Transform scale(double factor) {
        return new Transform(this.translation, this.rotationAndScale.scale(Math.sqrt(factor)));
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return this.rotationAndScale.getMagnitudeSquared();
    }

    public double[] toMatrix() {
        double x = this.rotationAndScale.getX();
        double y = this.rotationAndScale.getY();
        double z = this.rotationAndScale.getZ();
        double w = this.rotationAndScale.getW();
        double mm = this.rotationAndScale.getMagnitudeSquared();
        return new double[]{mm - 2.0D * y * y - 2.0D * z * z, 2.0D * x * y + 2.0D * z * w, 2.0D * x * z - 2.0D * y * w, 0.0D, 2.0D * x * y - 2.0D * z * w, mm - 2.0D * x * x - 2.0D * z * z, 2.0D * y * z + 2.0D * x * w, 0.0D, 2.0D * x * z + 2.0D * y * w, 2.0D * y * z - 2.0D * x * w, mm - 2.0D * x * x - 2.0D * y * y, 0.0D, this.translation.getX(), this.translation.getY(), this.translation.getZ(), 1.0D};
    }

    public geometry_msgs.Transform toTransformMessage(geometry_msgs.Transform result) {
        result.setTranslation(this.translation.toVector3Message(result.getTranslation()));
        result.setRotation(this.rotationAndScale.toQuaternionMessage(result.getRotation()));
        return result;
    }

    public Pose toPoseMessage(Pose result) {
        result.setPosition(this.translation.toPointMessage(result.getPosition()));
        result.setOrientation(this.rotationAndScale.toQuaternionMessage(result.getOrientation()));
        return result;
    }

    public PoseStamped toPoseStampedMessage(GraphName frame, Time stamp, PoseStamped result) {
        result.getHeader().setFrameId(frame.toString());
        result.getHeader().setStamp(stamp);
        result.setPose(this.toPoseMessage(result.getPose()));
        return result;
    }

    public boolean almostEquals(Transform other, double epsilon) {
        return this.translation.almostEquals(other.translation, epsilon) && this.rotationAndScale.almostEquals(other.rotationAndScale, epsilon);
    }

    public Vector3 getTranslation() {
        return this.translation;
    }

    public Quaternion getRotationAndScale() {
        return this.rotationAndScale;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Transform", new Object[]{this.translation, this.rotationAndScale});
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        boolean prime = true;
        byte result = 1;
        int result1 = 31 * result + (this.rotationAndScale == null?0:this.rotationAndScale.hashCode());
        result1 = 31 * result1 + (this.translation == null?0:this.translation.hashCode());
        return result1;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) {
            return true;
        } else if(obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Transform other = (Transform)obj;
            if(this.rotationAndScale == null) {
                if(other.rotationAndScale != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if(!this.rotationAndScale.equals(other.rotationAndScale)) {
                return false;
            }

            if(this.translation == null) {
                if(other.translation != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if(!this.translation.equals(other.translation)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250292/in-rosjava%EF%BC%8Chow-can-i-transform-the-%27odom%27-frame-to-%27map%27-frame?/) by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ues the method,maybe be not correct.

```
FrameTransform frameTransform = view.getFrameTransformTree().transform(GraphName.of("odom"), GraphName.of("map"));
```

See it
[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/249861/how-can-i-record-the-robot-trajectory-and-show-it-on-the-android-device/)

---

Originally posted by [Tony10012](https://answers.ros.org/users/27331/tony10012/) with karma: 56 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0